# Initializing time with its own timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'm quite new (and confused) with time in JavaScript..

I currently have time data to work with, and they are in the format of `DD-MMM-YYYY`, meaning it would be `23-Feb-2021`. This time is already in its own timezone, GMT-10. I'm trying to initialize it as GMT-10 so that I could get its appropriate epoch time.
I've done this:

```
date = new Date("23-Feb-2021") // This results in 2021-02-23T00:00:00.000Z
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is to get the time to be 2021-02-23T10:00:00.000Z, which I could then do a `getTime()` to get its epoch in ms. I understand I could probably hard code to +10 to the time I have, but the data I work with might vary so I'd like to figure a way to initialize the date with a specific timezone.

EDIT:
Here's an example of an outcome I'd want:

```
date = ("23-Feb-2021")

date = moment(date).format(); // 2021-02-23T00:00:00+00:00
date = date.replace("+00","+10");
date = new Date(msg.date); // 2021-02-22T14:00:00.000Z
date = date.getTime(); // 1614002400000 (2021-02-22T14:00:00.000Z)
```

In the end, 2021-02-22T14:00:00.000Z is what I'm trying to get, without having to iterate it a bunch of times like above and adding `+10`

Comment: Please be careful about the date string being passed in. `23-Feb-2021` becomes `Feb 23 -2021`. Consider creating the date using separate parameters?

Comment: You can use `toLocaleString()` to get a date with a specific timezone https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: @FelixHagspiel If I understand correctly, `toLocaleString()` will convert UTC > Any other timezone. Issue I have is that my `date` is not in UTC. I'd like to then later convert it to UTC.

Comment: Nitpick: `GMT-10` is not a timezone, it's a time offset. Timezones come with DST rules, present and historical, and so on. Fortunately you don't need to deal with that here.

Comment: @NikShafiqSirhan you are right. I saw that you are using `moment`, so you can use this: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

Comment: @Thomas—the definition of "timezone" is somewhat fluid. There are standard timezones based roughly on longitude that divide the world into one hour wide zones, typically used by [the military](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) (-10 is W). There is also the IANA concept of a representative location and the surrounding geographical area that has historically observed the same offsets, including DST. As far as I know, it's the only "timezone" that does that.  Longitudinal timezones have also been split in to half and quarter hour intervals.

Comment: @FelixHagspiel I guess that's possible only if I add a time to the date. If not, it'll set a default time `T10:00:00+10:00`.

Comment: If the host offset is -10 and the built–in parser correctly parses DD-MMM-YYYY format (and there is no guarantee of that), then it will be parsed as local and `new Date("23-Feb-2021").toISOString()` will return "2021-02-23T10:00:00Z", which is exactly what you want. And `Date.parse("23-Feb-2021")` will return the time value you're after too. No need for any library (or even a *Date* instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the timezone offset to your input string, and use an explicit [string format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse it:

```
let date = "23-Feb-2021"
date = moment(date + "-10:00", "D-MMM-YYYYZ")
console.log(date.format()) // 2021-02-23T11:00:00+01:00 (if local is GMT+1)
console.log(date.utc().format()) // 2021-02-23T10:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're already using moment.js, so add moment–timezone so you can parse timestamps in whatever IANA timezone you want. You can either choose a location with the offset rules you want (e.g. Pacific/Honolulu or Pacific/Tahiti for -10) or just a fixed offset like etc/GMT+10.

You can then format the value in any timezone, as UTC, or as a time value, e.g.

```js
// Timestamp
let d = "23-Feb-2021";

// Parse in specific IANA timezone
let m = moment.tz(d, 'D-MMM-YYYY', 'Pacific/Honolulu');

// Trigger UTC mode
m.utc()

// Show result
console.log(m.format())

// Get time value (ms since epoch)
console.log(m.valueOf());

// Parse using generic timezone/fixed offset
let g = moment.tz(d, 'D-MMM-YYYY', 'etc/GMT+10');
console.log(g.utc().format());

// Display timestamp for another timezone
console.log(moment.tz(g, 'Asia/Riyadh').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Note that for fixed offset timezones like etc/GMT+10, the sign is the opposite of the common offset (e.g. etc/GMT+10 is UTC-10) to be consistent with POSIX notation. However, moment.tz only has limited POSIX support in that it only recognises one hour offsets, not the full POSIX timezone notation, so you can't do say "etc/GMT-530" instead of Asia/Kolkata.